# how to put label in the same row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

By using http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css,
when I make a stack of labels, they are rendered in one column.

```
<label>..</label>
<label>..</label>
<label>..</label>
```

My goal is to put them in several columns depending by the width of the screen.

Here is my demo http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2557/

Any hints?

Answer (score 4):

Something like that?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3"><label>...</label> </div>
    <div class="span3"><label>...</label> </div>
    <div class="span3"><label>...</label> </div>
    <div class="span3"><label>...</label> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe a `.row-fluid` to make the row width depend on the width of the screen.

Comment: technically this wouldn't be correct if you want to take advantage of bootstrap's native .controls and .control-groups, as the op indicates in their fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Your code was almost correct. You left a couple of `<div>`s unclosed, but you also had the `.controls` and `.control-group`s nested incorrectly.

Here is an updated fiddle with your code fixed as well as an example with 3 columns (I also updated the javascript and added buttons for toggling the checkboxes. If you want to still use a checkbox for toggling you can modify the code pretty easily):

http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2624/

(make sure you scroll down in the html section of the fiddle to see the second example, in case you have a small screen)

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2559/) uses columns and will add more columns across as the screen size will allow. This is purely css and html.

[This script](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2561/) will size the columns based on the width of the container they are in. Simply specify the number of columns. This way all columns will always fit perfectly in a row. This uses jquery to resize the column widths.

You could float the labels with css.

```
<div class="column">
   <label class="float"></label>
   <input type="checkbox" value="2"> Monday
</div>
<div class="column">
   <label class="float"></label>
   <input type="checkbox" value="3"> Tuesday
</div>
...
<div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS

```
.column {
   width: 200px;
   float: left;
}

.clear {
   clear: both;
}
```